# Using fancytikzposter to define a block node with no title

Tags: tikz-styles, beamerposter, posters, tikzposter

I am using *fancytikzposter* to generate a poster  for a conference, I have three columns where the last block node of the first is continued in the second column.

Is their anyway to define a block node that does not have a title section?

I've probably missed something simple but this has been driving me nuts!

Thanks in advance.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{fancytikzposter} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{}
\setmargin{2}
\setblockspacing{2}
\setblocktitleheight{2}
\setcolumnnumber{3}

\usetemplate{4}

\usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=84.1cm, paperheight=118.9cm]{geometry}

\title{A pretty poster \\ 
\author{A very fustrated latex user$^{1,*}$
}}


\begin{document}
\ClearShipoutPicture
\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPicture}

\noindent % to have the picture right in the center
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \initializesizeandshifts

  \ifthenelse{\equal{\template}{1}}{ 
    \titleblock{72}{1}
  }{
    \titleblock{72}{1}
  }


\blocknode{Introduction}{
\lipsum[1-7]
}

\blocknode{Data \& Methods}{
\lipsum[8]
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% NEW COLUMN %%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\startsecondcolumn 

\blocknode{}{ 
What I really want is that little blue lip at the tip where the title is to go away.
}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: At the [fancytikzposter homepage](http://inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/fancytikzposter.html) you'll find: _NOTE that we joined our efforts with the tikzposter team, which resulted in an improved version 2.0 of the tikzposter class that you can find in [ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzposter). This class combines both good structure and nice layouts. The official webpage of our project is [bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/wiki](http://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/wiki)._ **I am not going to maintain this style.** Probably it is a good idea to switch to tikzposter.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comment, I happened to have a pre made poster in the old style so I though I could just use that but seeing that its no longer supported I better get with the times :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JMP says in the comment, the `tikzposter` class has taken the place of the `fancytikzposter` package. Using the class, blocks with empty titles doesn't get the title "area" in the block by default, so no extra work is needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usetheme{Envelope}
\author{A not so frustrated user}
\title{A pretty enough poster I hope}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3}
\block{Intro}{\lipsum[1]}
\column{0.3}
\block{}{\lipsum[2]}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah cheers, that's perfect! Ill port my current poster and just use tikzposter from now on. Thanks again!